# Trying to understand meaning of non-shell matacharacters in linux

Tags: linux

Can anyone help me understand the meaning of

```
grep "[0-9]\{2\}" filename
```

It is a non-shell matacharacter command.

Comment: Reading a [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) manual page might be a good start, as would reading about [*regular expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). And if you know about both, then can you please elaborate about your problem, what are you asking about? And what does it have to do with programming?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` needs the curly braces backslashed in quantifiers.

```sh
grep '[0-9]\{2\}'  #  n.b. the single quotes
```

In double quotes, `\{` is expanded as `{`, you need to backslash the backslash to get it through.